# Make a query to GA api with a service account credential

Tags: json, token, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I discovers the use of GA report API. Yours helps and precisions are very important for me. I want to get datas from GA report api with a json format.

I have making a test : I have installed the GA client with composer, create an app, a service account credential, and create the HelloAnalytics.php script. It's ok I get datas with this script.

But, I want to retrieve datas with a json format. Then, I think that this method is not good. I think that I must use a query to get datas from GA api. Isn't it?

If yes, how can I associate the service account credential with a query to GA api? By default, a query to GA api has need 1 token.

Can you explain me how to proceed? Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned composer which leades me to beleave that you are using php.   If you are using the PHP client library then it returns all the data to you as objects.

Google APIs by default return their data as Json but the client libraries to make it easier for you return it as an object.

You might try the json_encode($b) method which should if memory serves take an object and turn it into json for you.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, with json_encode() I can re-convert the output on json format. But, the datas of the output seems not to be well structured. Call a query to GA api is maybe a better solution. Have you any idea how to create this access_token for insert it in my url ? Thanks.

Comment: the client created should contain your access token

Comment: Here is the initialization section :// Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
  return $analytics; ///// How to get the access_token with this method? thanks